# Вывод значений из option

Tags: javascript, html

только начал изучать js!
Вопрос в следующем
Есть option

```
    <select name="" id="price">
  <option value="20000 р">Понедельник</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Вторник</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Среда</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Четверг</option>
  <option value="30000 р">Пятница</option>
  <option value="30000 р">Суббота</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Воскресенье</option>
</select>
```

Далее выводим с него значение в текст
(код взаимствовал)

```
<script>
const price = document.getElementById('price')
price.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  document.querySelector(".price_label").textContent = price[price.options.selectedIndex].value
}) 

</script>
```

Данный код выводит и вроде ок
но как сделать что бы при value в 30000 выводился отдельный текст с другим значением

допустим мы выбрали Субботу и он выводит 30000р, но во втором "p" выводилось значение 40000р

Comment: что такое "второе p" ? что значит "выводился отдельный текст" ?

Comment: Это как у Пятачка была объява "Посторонним В"... :)

Answer (score 1):

> как сделать что бы при value в 30000 выводился отдельный текст с другим значением.
> Допустим мы выбрали Субботу и он выводит 30000р, но во втором "p" выводилось значение 40000р

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const price = document.getElementById('price')
price.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const o = document.querySelectorAll(".price_label")
  const v = price[price.options.selectedIndex].value
  o[0].textContent = v
  o[1].textContent = parseInt(v) === 30000 ? '40000р' : ''
})
```

```html
<select name="" id="price">
  <option value="20000 р">Понедельник</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Вторник</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Среда</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Четверг</option>
  <option value="30000 р">Пятница</option>
  <option value="30000 р">Суббота</option>
  <option value="20000 р">Воскресенье</option>
</select>
<p class='price_label'></p>
<p class='price_label'></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! это то что нужно!